# Prevent that people type anything else then [Y or N]

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement

I need to make something that can prevent that people type anything else then [Y or N]
(Maby an if statement and a loop)

```
while(true)
{
    // The main program is up here
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again? [Y or N]");
    string answer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    if (answer == "Y")
    {
        continue;
    }
    else if (answer == "N")
    {
        return;
    }

    //maybe here
}
```

Comment: Change the `continue` and `return` to `break` statements in your loop and it should do what is needed.  Then outside the loop, you can process the Y and N inputs as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again? [Y or N]");
while (true)
{
    var k = Console.ReadKey();
    if (k.KeyChar == 'Y')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start playing...");
        break;
    }
    else if (k.KeyChar == 'N')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bye");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: ...Or `k.Key == ConsoleKey.Y` and `k.Key == ConsoleKey.N`